# как мне получить csrf token?

Tags: reactjs

Мне для реализации регистрации надо передать в пост запросе csrf token, для этого я пытаюсь достать из cookie csrf token, но переменной значение не присваивается.
вот мой код

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        password: '',
        re_password: '',
        csrfToken: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
        console.log(Cookies);
        setFormData({...formData, csrfToken });
        console.log(formData.csrfToken); 
    }, []);

    const {name, surname, email, password, re_password, csrfToken} = formData;
```

вот вывод cookie в консоль [image: вывод cookie], где csrf токена нет

а вот cookies в Network [image: cookies в Network]

Comment: Что такое `Cookies`? В браузерах по умолчанию такого нет

Comment: файлы куки - файлы, собирающие и хранящие информацию о пользователях, их предпочтениях и действиях на сайте

Comment: Если что, я решил проблему через бэк - написал функцию, которая брала этот токен из куки файлов 
```
def get_csrf(request):
    cookies = request.COOKIES
    csrf_token = cookies.get("csrftoken", get_token(request))
    return JsonResponse({'csrfToken': csrf_token})
```

Comment: Я знаю, что такое файлы куки. Я спрашивал не про них, я спрашивал про загадочную переменную `Cookies` в вашем коде